# シングルトンクラスフィールドの初期化に引数を使用したい

Tags: java

以下のクラスの"yyyy-MM-dd"の部分を引数で受け取った値に変更したいのですが、
記載方法が分からず質問致しました。

お分かりになる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

```
final public class SafeDateFormat_1 {

    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    };

    private SafeDateFormat_1() {
    }

    public static final Calendar getCalendar() {
        return formatter.get().getCalendar();
    }

    public static final void applyPattern(String pattern) {
        formatter.get().applyPattern(pattern);
    }

    public static final String format(Date date) {
        return formatter.get().format(date);
    }

    public static final Date parse(final String source, final ParsePosition pos) {
        return formatter.get().parse(source, pos);
    }

    public static final Date parse(String source) throws ParseException {
        return formatter.get().parse(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final void applyPattern(String pattern) {
    formatter.get().applyPattern(pattern);
}
```

このメソッドを呼ぶと `"yyyy-MM-dd"` 以外のパターンに設定できるという構造に見えます。